# docker micro-service cannot connect to bitcoin docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a micro-service `watchblockchain` that makes requests on `bitcoin` blockchain. When I use both services, everything works just fine.
Then I want to put those services in docker containers.
`watchblockchain` cannot communicate with the `bitcoin` docker.
I use docker image: kylemanna/bitcoind/

Here is my `bitcoin.conf` file:

```
disablewallet=1
printtoconsole=1
rpcauth=jfjobidon:123...xyz
testnet=1
txindex=1
server=1
rpcport=8332
```

I can open a console in the `bitcoin` container and verify that the blocks are downloading and I can make requests on the blockchain
ex: bitcoin-cli getblockcount

In `watchblockchain`, I have this connection config:

```
var clientBTC = new bitcoin.Client({
    host: 'bitcoin',
    port:  8332,
    user: 'jfjobidon',
    pass: 'Lw.....='
});
```

And I mapped `bitcoin` to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  watchblockchain:
    build: ./watchBlockchain
    depends_on:
      - redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```

When I launch: docker-compose up, I have the following error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8332

I think it is a network communication problem.

How can I get my `watchblockchain` service to communication with the `bitcoin` docker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the containers `hosts` file will differ from your hosts `hosts` file.

see it kind of like a VM.

Also 127.0.0.1 is the wrong address, you might need to configure the actual ip/hostname your host has and where the service is listening on inside the watchblockchain container.

So Problems:

- Your docker container knows nothing about the host `bitcoin`. an entry in your docker hosts `/etc/hosts` won't change that.
- Maybe your bitcoin service only binds to localhost `127.0.0.1` - this will also keep any docker container from connecting to it. Maybe you can configure it so that it binds to the docker bridge IP. So only all the docker containers are able to connect to it.
- It would be easier if your bitcoind would also be a docker container and was configured inside the `docker-compose.yml`. That way you could resolve the host using the container name. But still your bitcoind should be configured to bind on every interface.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I added the bitcoin docker in the docker-compose.yml and it solved my problem. Thanks :-)